# Derivative of $y = \sec(x) -2\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

According to wolfram the derivative of this is zero. This derivative though is part of a larger problem and I don't think it is possible for it to be zero. According to my own calculation the answer is $\sec(x) \tan(x) + 2\sin(x)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Wolfram doesn't give the derivative as zero http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+sec(x)-2cos(x)

Comment: You are right. I doubt Wolfram would come up with such a bald-faced lie.

Comment: Maybe I put it in wrong?

https://24.media.tumblr.com/e87eef6bfee00dfa68caa2f109000658/tumblr_n1h6krOXBj1tu3j9so1_1280.png

Comment: Wolfram may be useful if and only if you type correctly according to what the site really needs. Sometimes it's best to do the problem again twice and then go to Wolfram. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote it incorrectly and your answer is correct. What wolfram calculated was $(\sec (x))(-2\cos (x))$ which is actually $$\frac{1}{\cos (x)}\cdot\frac{-2\cos (x)}{1} =-2$$ And the derivative of $-2$ is $0$. When writing that equation in wolfram you need to pay careful attention to the **brackets** you use. As you would have now realized, $$\sec(x)-2\cos(x) \ne (\sec (x))(-2\cos (x))$$
There's no need for the extra brackets on the outside...This indicates **multiplying the two terms**.

Answer (score 0):

This derivative cannot possibly be zero. What you have is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$y=\sec(x)-2\cos(x)\\\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\tan(x)\sec(x)+2\sin(x)\neq 0$.

Indeed you are right.